# Should we delete/free the pointer array returned by Get<>ArrayElements if its corresponding Release<>ArrayElements mode is JNI_COMMIT?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

When calling the JNI function [`Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getprimitivetypearrayelements-routines) it will return a C `JNI NativeType` pointer array that may be a copy of the the original jarray, or a pointer that directly points to the original values of the jarray.

It also have a corresponding [`Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#releaseprimitivetypearrayelements-routines) to free the buffer when the mode is either `0` or `JNI_ABORT` and if the `jboolean` ouput `*isCopy` was set to `JNI_TRUE`, but not if the mode is `JNI_COMMIT`.

So my question is should we `free` / `delete[]` the pointer returned by the [`Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getprimitivetypearrayelements-routines) when we are done with it if we set the corresponding [`Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#releaseprimitivetypearrayelements-routines) mode to `JNI_COMMIT` since this mode does not free the buffer?

> JNI_COMMIT    copy back the content but do not free the elems buffer

---

**[EDIT]**

My bad I did not see it right away that `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion` does not return an array pointer, I updated my original second question as the main question.

Comment: It doesn't return a pointer. Therefore, the question is unclear. It's better if you show a [mcve].

Comment: @273K Sorry about that I updated the question now, I removed the original first question since its wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call free / delete[] on a array pointer returned by `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`, whether the native array 'looks into' the Java array or is a copy allocated by JVM. You should call `Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` when you are done with this array, with **mode** either `0` or `JNI_ABORT`.

But between `Get…` and final `Release…`, you may need to sync the native and Java sides of the array. This is achieved by calling `Release…` with **mode=**`JNI_COMMIT`. This way, you may call `Release…` as many times as you wish before you finally ***release*** the native array.

Note that in the end, your JNI code should also release the reference to the Java array.

Comment: Re your final sentence, that’s not necessary if it came in as a parameter, if you are returning it as the return value, …

Answer (score 5):

> Should we free / delete[] the pointer returned by the `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion`?

No.

The operation is a copy operation that copies *some* of the data in the array into a buffer supplied by the caller.  It doesn't "acquire" the array, and it doesn't return a pointer.  (The documentation says that return type is `void`.)

Also, unlike `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements`, the documentation makes no mention of a release or free method, or of any requirement to release or free anything.

However, the caller *is* responsible any memory management of the buffer that it supplied in the `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion` call.

---

> Should we free / delete[] the pointer returned by the `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` if we set the corresponding `Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` mode to `JNI_COMMIT` since this mode also does not free the buffer?

See this answer from Alex Cohn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75969187/139985.  `JNI_COMMIT` mode doesn't actually release the buffer.  You must call `Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` *again* to release it.